# How can I jump to a specific page number in presentation mode in Okular?

Tags: kde-plasma-5, okular

Is there any shortcut that allows me to jump to a specific page number when beeing in presentation mode in Okular? I tried to just enter the page number and press enter (as I'm used to from Power Point), but unfortunately that does not work.

Comment: Suggestion: Describe your hardware setup when doing the presentation; do you use a laptop with an external display, or using desktop PC with dual monitor? If yes, I will update my answer with an alternative method (may be less known to end-users).

Comment: I just use my laptop to read in full screen, no external presentation device.

Comment: The 'Full Screen Mode (Ctrl+Shift+F)' in Okular can already jump to any page easily by using 'Go to Page... (Ctrl+G)'. Is there any reason for not using the full screen mode?

Comment: I prefer presentation mode, because then I really see the slides automatically in full screen. With Full Screen Mode you still have the navigation previews on the left and slides are not automatically filling the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the presentation mode in Okular cannot do that.

[The Okular Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kdegraphics/okular/presentationMode.html) has hinted that the only way to jump to a specific page in presentation mode is to use the helper bar that will appear at top of the screen.

> When in presentation mode, you have an helper bar located on the top of the screen. Just move the mouse cursor to the top of the screen to make it appear.

The page navigation is located at the top-left corner of the bar.

[image: Okular presentation mode with highlight at top-left corner]

To jump to a specific page in presentation mode: When the top bar appears, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once to give focus and highlight the small text box and type the page number of choice, then finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to the specific page.

Follow up with comment from OP:

> I prefer presentation mode, because then I really see the slides automatically in full screen. With Full Screen Mode you still have the navigation previews on the left and slides are not automatically filling the screen.

The full screen mode in Okular can appear as clean as the presentation mode, as long as user is willing to configure. KDE makes that possible by on-demand to meet different user preferences, hence not automatic.

This is Okular in full screen mode, after some configuration:

[image: Okular in Full Screen Mode]

Some configuration in detail:

- Go to **Settings > Configure Okular...** and then, under "General Options" - "Appearance", **empty the checkbox** for "Show scrollbars"
- Go to **View** and select **Fit Page** for presentation slide, or select other options, depending on the document page size
- Press <kbd>F7</kbd> to show or hide Navigation Panel
- Finally, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to enter or exit the full screen mode.

**Optional**: Go to **Settings > Configure Shortcuts...** to change any keyboard shortcuts in Okular. The "Page Bar" can be shown or hidden, as well as each action "Fit Page", "Fit Width", "Fit Window to Page" can all be changed by user on-demand.

In full screen mode, the page bar at bottom of the screen is left visible on purpose: This way, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, the user only needs to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once (or twice if out of focus) to be able to change the page number, which is similar to the presentation mode as described earlier.

Personally, I appreciate the KDE-way of allowing user to configure almost everything on-demand. So I would recommend KDE users to configure first, at least once, then enjoy the "user-configured automatic" setup for lifetime.

**TL;DR** To jump to a specific page in Okular: In presentation mode, user has no choice but to use the mouse cursor; in full screen mode, user has the choice to configure beforehand to meet user preferences.

Comment: Another possibility is to click in the upper right corner (just below the appearing top bar) and use the "ring" to jump (approximately for big documents) to any page in the document.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

If Okular does not provide a keybinding by itself (as pointed out by the previous answer), you could create a workaround: Okular at least offers a way to start in presentation mode and immediately jump to a specified page. This could be leveraged by a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# close all instances of okular
killall okular

# reopen okular
okular --presentation -p "${2}" "${1}"
```

If you [bind](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-utils/krusader/key_bindings.html) e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to `/path/to/script /path/to/myPresentation.pdf 5`, this will kill the currently running instance of Okular and afterwards start *myPresentation.pdf* on page 5.

It is not nice, it is not pretty, but it works.

PS: The script could even be extended to grab the filename of the currently running presentation for reuse before killing it.

Comment: +1 for the script approach.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, if this helps you for your specific problem:

If you want to open a document directly on a given page, you can use

```
okular -p 3 --presentation YourFile.pdf
```

for example to start your presentation with page 3.

Else the keyboard-only sequence when being already in presentation mode is:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> to go back to presentation.

It is definitely a nice and missing feature of Okular. Make a [request to the developers](https://okular.kde.org/contact.php).

Comment: Instead of copying my answer you could just have upvoted / edited it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think our answers match completely. You do not provide a solution to go to pages with more than two digits for example. Better let the OP decide.

Comment: +1 because this is not a duplicate answer, but rather clarification of doing in both command-line and graphical methods. Nothing in this answer suggested using script like the earlier answer.